# Is there a fast way to expand matrices n times by duplicating each line?

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, julia

For example, `[1 1 ; 2 2 ; 3 3]` becomes

```
[1 1
 1 1
 1 1
 2 2
 2 2
 2 2
 3 3
 3 3
 3 3]
```

I am using this:
`expander(orig,mult::Int) = orig[ceil(Int,(1:size(orig,1)*mult)/mult),:];` in Julia and the following in Matlab:

```
function expanded = expander(original,multiplier)
   expanded = original(ceil((1:size(original,1)*multiplier)/multiplier),:);
end
```

Another matlab only way to do it is this:

```
expanded = kron(original,ones(multiplier,1));
```

I would prefer a superfast julia option if it exists.

Comment: `kron` is the best way to do it, and it's pretty fast in Julia as of this issue getting fixed: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/4958

Comment: What is stopping you from using `kron` the same way in Julia?

Comment: If kron is the fastest way, that's what I'll use. Is it faster because it avoids changing from int to double, then back?

Comment: As you have tagged this question with `[matlab]` also: you could use `repmat`. However no clue how fast it is in comparison.

Comment: For Matlab R2015a+ try [repelem](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html), e.g., `A=[1 1;2 2;3 3];` `repelem(A,3,1)`

Comment: Matthias, `repmat` doesn't work, but I just discovered that as of r2015a, there is a purpose built function for this, `repelem()` edit: horchier, didn't see your post, but this is clearly the answer for matlab.

Comment: @BFH. Among other things, yes. Also, check out https://github.com/JuliaLang/MATLAB.jl

Comment: @MadPhysicist, Yeah, thanks, I'm actually porting a small portion of a large matlab project to Julia because it heavily loops and function passes. It bogs down in matlab, so I'm seeing whether I can just port it, or if I need to reduce complexity. I may be able to pull some things out of the loops and calculate them ahead of time, which will be very helpful.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, Incidentally, is https://github.com/twadleigh/jlcall any good?

Comment: Honestly no idea. I only just recently started looking into Julia. It looks pretty legit though.

Comment: I really think your best option is Julia's `kron` here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't prove that `kron` is fastest, but I compared its time to how long it would just take to populate a similarly sized Array with ones, and `kron` did quite well:

```
original = [1 1 ; 2 2 ; 3 3];
multiplier = 3*10^6;

@time begin
    for idx = 1:100
        expanded = kron(original,ones(multiplier));
    end
end
## 9.199143 seconds (600 allocations: 15.646 GB, 9.05% gc time)

@time begin
    for idx = 1:100
        myones = [ones(multiplier*size(original,1))  ones(multiplier*size(original,1))];
    end
end
## 12.746123 seconds (800 allocations: 26.822 GB, 14.86% gc time)
```

**Update** In response to comments by David Sanders, here are tests wrapped in a function.  The reason I did the tests globally, which I know isn't normal best practice, is because it seemed quite plausible to me that the objects might get created globally.

```
function kron_test(original, multiplier)
    for idx = 1:100
        expanded = kron(original,ones(multiplier));
    end
end

function ones_test(original, multiplier)
    for idx = 1:100
        myones = [ones(multiplier*size(original,1))  ones(multiplier*size(original,1))];
    end
end

## times given after first function call to compile
@time kron_test(original, multiplier);  ## 11.107632 seconds (604 allocations: 15.646 GB, 23.98% gc time)
@time ones_test(original, multiplier);  ## 15.849761 seconds (604 allocations: 26.822 GB, 33.50% gc time)
```

Comment: Remember never to time *anything* in global scope, it means nothing.

Comment: @DavidP.Sanders Good point in general.  But, if you are going to be creating variables globally, isn't a global timing appropriate?  I'd be happy to know if this isn't correct though.

Comment: If you pass the variables in you get a different one in the local scope with the same name. You can switch between them with the local and global keywords.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'd just use [`repeat`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/linalg/#Base.repeat):

```
repeat(original, inner=(multiplier, 1))
```

Unlike `kron`, it's very readable and understandable.  Unfortunately it is quite a bit slower.  Even so, I'd only use `kron` if you've identified it as a performance bottleneck.  While it's faster for computers to execute, it's much slower for humans to understand what's going on… and the performance of `repeat` should eventually get better (it's [issue #15553](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/15553)).

---

Edit: As of Julia 1.2, `repeat` has indeed gotten significantly faster.  It now rivals `kron`:

```
julia> @btime kron($original,ones($multiplier));
  81.039 ms (6 allocations: 160.22 MiB)

julia> @btime repeat($original, inner=($multiplier, 1));
  84.087 ms (27 allocations: 137.33 MiB)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
a = [1 1 ; 2 2 ; 3 3]
a = a' #matrices are in column major order in julia, should  be faster this way
a = repmat(a,1,n) 
a = sortcols(a)
```

Unfortunatelly I have no clue wheter this method is "superfast" but it's relatively simple and intuitive